# Recursively check if array is in ascending order

Tags: c

If the array is in ascending order I should return -1.

else, I should return the first Index that "ruins" the ascending order.

The function should be recursive.

please help ;) thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Please read this before asking a question http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: @Alex - there's actually a shortcut for letting people know about the faq it's: `[faq]` ends up looking like this: [faq]

Answer (score 3):

Recursive func that

- returns -1 if array is in ascending order
- returns the index of the first item that fails (means < a[i-1])
- takes only the two parameters

Algo

```
int recur(int *a, int n) {
  static int i=0;
  if (i >= n-1) return -1;
  if (a[i] > a[i+1]) return i+1;
  return i++, recur(a, n);
}
```

Edit from comment: function that can be called several times (not reentrant)

```
int recur(int *a, int n) {
  static int i=0;
  if (i >= n-1 || a[i] > a[i+1]) {
    int ret = (i >= n-1 ? -1 : i+1);
    i = 0;
    return ret;
  }
  return i++, recur(a, n);
}
```

Comment: +1 concise and meets the requirements.

Comment: This function can be called only once... Subsequent calls will work incorrectly...

Answer (score 1):

To design a recursive function, a good idea is to use tail-recursion (which will be turn to iterative with a good compiler).

```
int CheckAscendingOrder (const int *array, int size, int idx, int prec)
{
  int res;

  if (idx >= size)
  {
    res = -1;
  }
  else if (array[idx] < prec)
  {
    res = idx;
  }
  else
  {
    res = CheckAscendingOrder (array, size, idx + 1, array[idx]);
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Bleh.. really sorry guys but the function recieves only 2 paramaters, a pointer to the array and its size ;(

Comment: And in a bad compiler, or any compiler in debug mode, it will overflow your stack and you'll get annoying crashes. Tail-recursion in C is for small amounts of data and academic papers. Handle with care.

Comment: @roeeleon: so write two functions then: one that takes two parameters and calls the other. That's what everybody else does.

Comment: @ams: In that case I don't understand the difference with classic recursion. As far I can see, there will be the same amount of stack frames.

Comment: Incidentally, my criticisms are not really levelled at @Kirilenko because your question requires recursion. This is a proper solution.

Comment: @Kirilenko: exactly. Without the compiler optimization enabled they are exactly the same. I just prefer a solution that also works when I build it in debug mode, with optimization disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ArrayAscending(int a[], int n)
{
static int i=0;
if(i==n) return 1;
return (a[i]<a[i+++1] && ArrayAscending(a, n));
}
```

Returns 0 -- if the array is not in ascending order.
Returns 1 -- if the array is in ascending order.

Answer (score -1):

Something like that should work... (But describe what you mean by recursive...)

```
 int ascending_check (int* in_tab, int tab_size)
{
   int i=0;
   int previous_value = INT_MIN //in limits.h

   for (i=0;i<tab_size; i++)
   {
      if(previous_value >= in_tab[i])
      {
          return i;
      }
   }

   return -1; //Ascending tab.
}
```

Next time, please give us more information on what you tried :)

Comment: This is not recursive.

Comment: `But describe what you mean by recursive` - recursive means [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))...

Comment: @Cong Xu I never said it was recursive. But it does the purpose... He said : It SHOULD be not it MUST be. I don't see where my mistake is in this situation...

Comment: @Mike My question was more : Why use recursive in this case ?